# Why are the last 4 trxs in the mempool stuck?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod

They have been there for days and do not clear. All the newer trxs seem to jump over them. Their size and fees paid are no greater than other trxs that are getting confirmed immediately. So I was wondering why they got stuck so I can avoid making the same mistake.

Comment: They seem to maybe be on the wrong chain or an error on the block explorers. my node does not have those transactions in the mempool for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I have heard those tx's were created with the 0.10.0 wallet and therefore used the deprecated ASNL signatures. After the ringCT hardfork the 0.10.1 software is a minimum requirement. Tx's created with older versions will not be included in blocks.